# PHP datatables file exporting

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables, export-to-pdf

how to merge this two initialisation to one initialisation
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var dataTable=$('#example').DataTable({
             "processing": true,
             "serverSide":true,
             "ajax":{
                 url:"fetchoffice1.php",
                 type:"post"
             }
         });

     });
 </script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        } );
      } );
 </script>
```

Comment: ok, so what's the issue?

Comment: This error is triggered by passing in options to a DataTables constructor object when the DataTable instance for the selected node has already been initialised.

Comment: So why not just combine them into one?

Comment: can u write it for me please. im still confused.the data in the table does not appear when exporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what the issue is. Just combine the object, and initialize it once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:{
            url: "fetchoffice1.php",
            type: "post"
        }
    });
});
```